# Passing a prototype to Object.Create()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

EDIT :  Child is an object. Sorry im pretty new to this

I am confused with how Object.create() works. I understand that whatever you pass into it returns a new object with that argument as the prototype. My teacher listed this as an example of classical inheritance :

`child.prototype=Object.create(parent.prototype)`

what does this accomplish (in terms of inheritance) that the example below doesn't:

`child = Object.create(parent)`

Comment: `prototypes` are really for functions that are `constructors`, but they are Objects themselves. Those aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: you didn't mention what `child` is, it makes a big difference whether `child` is a function or a regular object..

Answer (score 1):

**let's explain the second Part of your question first**

based on your answer `child` is an object and not a function

`child = Object.create(parent)`

what will this do?

1- this will create an object called `child`
**strong text**
2- it will use the object `parent` as the prototype `__proto__` of the object `child` so if `parent` has a property called `lastName : Thomson` then `child` now
has access to this property via its  `__proto__` property
same goes for any method/function in the `parent` object, the `child` object has now access to it.

**now to the first part:**

`child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype)`

what will this do?

1- this assumes that there's an already created object called `child` somewhere 
in the script

2- it assigns a property called `prototype` to the `child` object so now you can write something like this `child.prototype` and get some result

3- the `Object.create(parent.prototype)` runs converting/making the property you just created `child.prototype` an object and then making the `__proto__` of that object equal to 
`parent.prototype` which suppose to be an object, I mean `parent.prototype` needs to be an object for this to work.

---

**NOTE:**

object instances (regular objects such as `let obj = {};` ) don't have 
a `.prototype` property but they automatically inherit something called `__porto__`
from their constructor which unfortunately also called prototype

constructors/functions on the other hand have a `.prototype` property which you can 
manipulate just like any other property, this `.prototype` property is passed later on to the instances of that constructor/function

it's a pretty interesting topic I encourage you to dig deep into this if you want to know more about javascript.

Answer (score -1):

In `test1` we can see that `Constructor1.prototype` did not inherit from `Constructor2.prototype` using `Object.create`. In `test2` you can see that `prototype` inheritance occurred, as the `Object` created by calling `new` has the properties that came from `Constructor1`. `test3` shows that `prototype` assignment like that doesn't work at all.

```js
function Constructor1(test = 'see'){
  this.test = test; this.yeah = 7; 
  this.fun = function(q){
    this.test = q;
    return this;
  }
}
function Constructor2(q = true){
  this.noInheritedProps = q;
}
Constructor2.prototype = Object.create(Constructor1.prototype);
const test1 = new Constructor2, obj1 = new Constructor1('with argument'), test2 = Object.create(obj1);
console.log(test1); console.log(test2); Constructor2.prototype = Constructor1.prototype;
const test3 = new Constructor2('once again true');
console.log(test3);
```